# RED streaming interface

Tags: streaming, red

I need to get a live video stream from a RED camera into a proprietary app running under OSX (though I can switch to Windows if necessary). I'm unable to find any information about getting a live preview from a RED camera.

We have a video shoot tomorrow. The video is going to be shown in a 3D environment, and we need to make sure that the actors' eyeline, etc. is correct for their position within the simulation. Note that we're recording 2D video, not 3D - the flat video will be placed on a plane within a 3D environment.

Preview resolution is unimportant - 320x200 would work fine for this stage of production.

The best solution I have at the moment is to tape a webcam to the side of the RED and use that as the input to my application. That will work, but I don't think the camera owner will be thrilled with my use of duct tape.

My app works fine with a webcam interface, but somehow I doubt that RED has something like that available.

HELP.

(In case it matters, the application is a Unity3D app running under OSX. Video is being displayed within a 3D room on an Oculus Rift.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tap the SDI output port of any RED camera and feed that to a hardware device that reads 1080p video.  Blackmagic make some things that translate SDI -> internal video stream via PCIe card (Decklink), USB (Ultrastudio), and Thunderbolt (Ultrastudio for Thunderbolt).  This would be the easy way to do it.

If you have a RED DRAGON (EPIC or SCARLET) with the latest firmware, there's a RED Tether option.  It requires a special LEMO->RJ45 cable, and it feeds live video out the ethernet port.  See [this article](http://www.reduser.net/forum/showthread.php?131190-Dragon%B4s-Leash-(aka-RED-TETHER)) for more info.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the EPIC camera we were using had an HDMI output. I actually wound up pointing a cheap webcam at one of the monitors and feeding that into my app. Not ideal, but sufficient for the task at hand.